# Android application file path

Tags: android, filepath

So I've built some code to download a file which works fine and I have set it to download into the applications directory which works. it's stored in the application folder /files/dltest

My issue is with checking programatically wether or not the file exists, I've tried methods one stackoverflow and for some reason I can only get my hard coded path to work.

```
/sdcard/Android/Data/com.test.alihassan.download/files/dltest/REQS.pdf
```

Using built in methods to retrieve the path gives me the same path but with /data/data/com.... and this doesn't work

Comment: Try `String path = c.getFilesDir().toString()+"/files/dltest/REQS.pdf";` You missed that `.../files/..` part. Does it work now?

Comment: Nope, Log shows that as getting /data/data/com.test.alihassan.download/files/files/dltest/REQS.pdf

Comment: Can you log the exact file path after download? Like log it just after download

Comment: /data/data/com.test.alihassan.download/files/dltest/REQS.pdf

Comment: Yet `String path = c.getFilesDir().toString()+"/dltest/REQS.pdf";` does not work? Check if the folder contains files like `File[] dlFiles = new File(c.getFilesDir().toString+"/dltest").listFiles();` Then check if `dlFiles` contains anything and log file names like `dlFiles[0].getName();` Just making sure the file downloaded and was saved to disk.

Comment: Maybe your download code is not correct. A very small mistake can cause a lot of pain.

Comment: Found no files in that directory using that
Thing is I'm using a file manager on one of the devices and the file is downloading to my application directory/files/dltest and when I use my string as the path the statement executes fine. It's only when I use a method to get the location and I get data/data vs sdcard that I seem to have issues

        String p = "/sdcard/Android/Data/com.test.alihassan.download/files/dltest/REQS.pdf";
works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File mydir = context.getFilesDir();
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile/path/fileNmae");
if(fileWithinMyDir.exists()){
    //exists
   }else{
    //not  exists
 }
```

**Update:**

```
        //File mydir = this.getFilesDir();
        File mydir = this.getExternalFilesDir("/dltest/REQS.pdf");
        if (mydir.exists()) {
            //exists
        } else {
            //not  exists
        }
```

Comment: @AliHassan show when you download code so we can figur our your correct path?

Comment: request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), "/dltest", "REQS.pdf");
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);}

Comment: @AliHassan thats not internal path its external path try the updated section code.